# Flutter, Android Unable to load Maven meta-data from ~ Build error solution

Tags: android, flutter, stripe-payments

I am using 'stripe_payment: ^1.0.6' used for integrating stripe in a flutter. I am got this error for Gradle sync.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:processDebugResources'. Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.

Could not resolve net.minidev:json-smart:[1.3.1,2.3].
Required by: project :app > project :stripe_payment > com.stripe:stripe-android:10.4.6 > com.stripe:stripe-3ds2-android:1.2.2 > com.nimbusds:nimbus-jose-jwt:7.8

Failed to list versions for net.minidev:json-smart. Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://google.bintray.com/exoplayer/net/minidev/json-smart/maven-metadata.xml.

Could not get resource 'https://google.bintray.com/exoplayer/net/minidev/json-smart/maven-metadata.xml'.
Could not GET 'https://google.bintray.com/exoplayer/net/minidev/json-smart/maven-metadata.xml'. Received status code 502 from server: Bad Gateway

Answer (score 2):

Problem that google.bintray.com is down but version of net.minidev:json-smart is not specified strictly.

This **[1.3.1,2.3]** mean it has versions range [Gradle Declaring Versions and Ranges](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/single_versions.html)

1. Search for versions of *net.minidev:json-smart* [Maven search](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.minidev/json-smart). We have 2.3 & 2.3.1
2. Constrain your transitive dependency with maximum possible version 2.3.1

Edit your project **app/build.gradle**:

```
dependencies {
  ...
  constraints {
    implementation('net.minidev:json-smart') {
        version {
            strictly '2.3.1'
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a known issue: https://github.com/jonasbark/flutter_stripe_payment/issues/338

However this plugin is also deprecated/unmaintained: https://github.com/jonasbark/flutter_stripe_payment/blob/master/migration.md

The author recommends using `flutter_stripe` instead: https://github.com/flutter-stripe/flutter_stripe#features